# Unable to import Django in Python3.4

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu (14.04). I just installed django using `sudo pip install Django`.

This is what is happening:

```
rpr@rpr-Inspiron-3521:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> 

rpr@rpr-Inspiron-3521:~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
>>>
```

What should I do to be able to use Django from Python3.4?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401132/how-can-i-install-django-for-python-3-x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just write:

```
sudo pip3 install Django
```

But better use virtualenv like Daniel said.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401132/how-can-i-install-django-for-python-3-x)

If you cannot run pip3 install it with the [following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

Answer (score 1):

pip is presumably installed for Python 2, not Python 3. You may have a version named `pip3` that targets Py3.

However, it would be better to use a virtualenv.

Comment: check my solution. it explains how to install the pip3